# передача textarea в data

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте, как мне из textarea передать в data?

```
var datas = $(this).serialize();
var datas = {txt: $("#txtcom").text()};

data: datas,

<textarea id='txtcom'></textarea>
```

Пробовал так, но выдает пустоту

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: Получение содержимого из textarea `$('#txtcom').val()`

Comment: Вот с val работает